# Reverse proxy failing with unknown error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to self host plausible analytics. So far I've installed docker, and started the docker containers. I've also ensured nginx is running, has a valid config, allowed ports 80 and 443 through ufw, and configured nginx with the domain: `https://plausible.example.com`.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
   server {
    server_name plausible.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/plausible.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/plausible.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

 server {
    if ($host = plausible.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name plausible.example.com;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot 
}
```

The problem is when I try to visit `plausible.example.com` I get a `502 bad gateway` error. When I check the nginx error logs I get this error:

`[error] 935230#935230: *579224 recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream`

I've tried to find a solution to this error but I haven't been able too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I should also add that in the plausible env variables, the host name is: `https://plausible.example.com`

Comment: Does the Plausible server run in HTTP or HTTPS mode at port 8000? One reason for the error might be that it is running HTTPS, and you have configured HTTP as the protocol.

Comment: The plausible server only runs on http

Comment: What are the contents of nginx `error.log` and Plausible logs?